# Reading JSON data through highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am trying to read through a JSON file in highcharts and displaying the result. My json file is as thus:

```
[
  {
    "key": "01/01/2009", 
    "value": {
       "Actual:number": "10000", 
       "Predicted:number": "30000"
    }
  }, 
  {
   "key": "01/02/2009", 
   "value": {
      "Actual:number": "40000", 
      "Predicted:number": "40000"
    }
  }, 
  {
   "key": "01/03/2009", 
   "value": {
      "Actual:number": "50000", 
      "Predicted:number": "20000"
   }
  }
]
```

My issue is how to properly access the nested data in the "value" key. From what i have tried so far, I can access the date key but not the values. In what way can I be able to access the data for displaying?

```js
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var processed_json = new Array();

        $.getJSON('http://localhost:9000/test.json', function(data){

            // populate series

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                processed_json.push([new Date(data[i].key).getTime(), data[i].value]);
            }

            // draw chart

            $('#container').highcharts({

                chart: {
                    type: "column"
                },
                title: {
                    text: "Sample data"
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    allowDecimals: false,
                    title: {
                        text: ""
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Date of Repairs',
                    data: processed_json
                }]
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

Comment: `data[i].value` is an object. Which value do you want? `data[i].value["Actual:number"]` or `data[i].value["Predicted:number"]`?

Comment: I want to get 'value[actual:number]' but when I tried that it didn't work. Am I meant to use '$.each'?

Comment: Doesn't work how? Did you parse the value to a number?

Comment: I tried parsing it and checking in the console but it returned **NaN**

Comment: `parseInt(data[i].value["Actual:number"])`

Comment: Yes I have done that and it returns 'NaN

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lfaw5ggu/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100801/discussion-between-gbenro-skenzy-selere-and-halvor-strand).